# Is there a windows phone 8.0 platform matrix type?

Tags: c#, opencv, matrix, windows-phone, c++-cx

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.0 public API that is actually a wrapper around C++ written in C++/CX and should interface to C# (or C++/CX).
I need to return a matrix object(which is a OpenCV `cv::Mat` originally) to client somehow. Attempts to find WP platform matrix type were unsuccessful.

What should be the best way to present the matrix object to a client?

There seems to be a `Windows::Foundation::Numerics::Matrix4x4` and `Matrix3x2` types but they are only available on Win 10 and not on WP 8.0.

I was thinking of using `Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Matrix` but I don't want to use a XAML object.

Is there some generic Matrix type on WP 8.0 platform that I can use or should I just return an array of doubles or something?

Comment: `Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Matrix` is available for WP 8.1, not WP 8.0. You could still use it for inspiration, and define your own matrix type just the same as a `public value struct` in C++/CX.

Comment: Oh yes. You are correct about `Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Matrix`. So that is definitely out of the question. Now I have to decide if I will use `public value struct` or a `Platform::Array<double>`.

Answer (score 0):

> OpenCV cv::Mat originally

n-dimensional dense numerical single-channel or multi-channel array? Sorry, no built-in class exist regardless on the Windows version.

> Matrix4x4 and Matrix3x2 types

they’re completely different from `cv::Mat`. They are comparable to `cv::Matx<float, 4, 4>` and `cv::Matx<float, 3, 2>`

If you only need small matrices like float 4x4 where size is known at compile time, you can borrow the structures from [MonoGame](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/tree/develop/MonoGame.Framework). The license is OK, it's MS-PL, however the quality isn’t ideal: generally works, but prepare to fix some occasional bugs.